# Same CSS3 gradient acting differently

Tags: css, background, gradient

I used a [css3 generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create a gradient background.

It works on a static html page I built.

When I run my aspx there is no backgruond, though firebug shows the rule, with no conflicts, and even displays the gradient when I hover on the rule in firebug.

I [fiddled it](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/VgxJz/1/) - doesn't work there either.

Here's the code:

```
body {
  background: #a0d3ff; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #a0d3ff 0%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a0d3ff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #a0d3ff 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #a0d3ff 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #a0d3ff 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #a0d3ff 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a0d3ff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your css doesn't seem to apply to anywhere!...

Comment: True, fiddle isn't complete, it's supposed to be on the body. I fixed it, didn't help.

Comment: see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VgxJz/2/ works good for me your fiddle not contain html, body so u cant see the background gradient.

Comment: Your fiddle does not have a body...

Comment: OK, seems that was the problem. My original file had elements positioned `absolute` all over, no real body to display. Thank you

Comment: Just a comment: `-ms-linear-gradient` is not needed. IE10 supports `linear-gradient` (standard syntax, no prefix) and IE9 does not support gradients at all. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients